# Return results for id if later record meets criteria

Tags: mysql, filter, case, where-clause

Sample data:

```
date   id   case   type    case_review_date
11/1   1    90     Review  11/1
12/27  1    23     Block
1/1    1    12     Review  1/1
1/2    1    45     Failed
1/3    1    78     Review  1/3
1/3    3    62     Failed
1/1    2    33     Review  1/1
1/10   2    63     Failed
```

Goal is to only return rows where there is a Failed type for an id within 7 days of a Review date. So for this example, it should only return id 1 case 12. Using MySQL. Having a really hard time thinking through the logic on this one. Would really appreciate any help!

Attempted the following and it does not seem to be working correctly, or isolating it based on ID. Instead, it returns all Review entries if there is any Failed case within 7 days, regardless of if it is for the same ID or not. So it returns the following:

```
date   id   case   type    case_review_date
1/1    1    12     Review  1/1
1/3    3    62     Failed
```

```
select *
from casetable
where exists
   (select 1
    from casetable
    where casetable.type = 'Failed' and DATEDIFF(day, casetable.date, casetable.case_review_date) <= 7)
```

Comment: Could there ever be more than one review date?  If so, could you update your sample data to reflect this?

Comment: Yes, there can be multiple review dates. Will update to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

You could use exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT date, id, `case`, type
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    type = 'Review' AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.type = 'Review' AND
                      t2.date < t1.date) AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
            WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.type = 'Failed' AND
                  DATEDIFF(t2.date, t1.date) <= 7);
```